# Azure AD When to use API Permissions vs Expose an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently developing a react web app that will use Microsoft's [MSAL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser) package to authenticate users to ensure only users within our tenant may access the Api.

I've built a http function app called **TARGET_APP** with a python function that accesses our data and returns it. I registered it to our Azure AD enterprise applications.

Now according to the documentation for proper "On Behalf Of" calls to work I am to register another app to represent my react client app, called **CALLER_APP** I registered this as well, and set up the scopes I need which include email, user.read, and the **TARGET_APP**'s exposed Api.

Example of my **CALLER_APP** permissions here:

[image: CALLER_APP Permissions]

However when attempting to authorize with the **CALLER_APP** from the client, via MSAL with the scopes in the image, I get a prompt saying "Admin consent required"

Snippet from my authentication flow (**handleLogin** is the initiating function called) :

```js
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/",
      clientId: "CALLER_APP_CLIENT_ID",
      redirectUri,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: redirectUri
  },
  cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage"
  }
}

// NOTE I have subbed out my actual caller scope with "CALLER_APP_SCOPE" for this post
const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["CALLER_APP_SCOPE", "user.read", "email"]
};

async function handleLogin(instance) {
  const loginUrl = await getLoginUrl(instance, loginRequest);
  const loginResult = await launchWebAuthFlow(instance, loginUrl);

  // Acquire token
  const { accessToken } = await acquireToken(instance, loginRequest);

  console.log(accessToken)
}

/**
 * Generates a login url
 */
 async function getLoginUrl(instance, request) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance.loginRedirect({
          ...request,
          onRedirectNavigate: (url) => {
              resolve(url);
              return false;
          }
      }).catch(reject);
  });
}

/**
* Generates a login url
*/
async function launchWebAuthFlow(instance, url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
          interactive: true,
          url
      }, (responseUrl) => {
          // Response urls includes a hash (login, acquire token calls)
          if (responseUrl.includes("#")) {
            instance.handleRedirectPromise(`#${responseUrl.split("#")[1]}`)
                  .then(resolve)
                  .catch(reject)
          } else {
              // Logout calls
              resolve();
          }
      })
  })
}

/**
  * Attempts to silent acquire an access token, falling back to interactive.
  */
 async function acquireToken(instance, request) {
  return instance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.accessToken);
  }).catch(async (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    storage.set({'loggedState': false});
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Most of this code is taken directly from the documentation,

Calling the **handleLogin** function initiates the authentication flow successfully, however when I log in with my Microsoft credentials I receive the "App needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant" popup.

I double checked my scopes and ensured none require admin consent, as well as I have gone into the enterprise apps user consent and permissions settings and enabled user consent on low impact scopes as you can see here:

**Enterprise Setting:**

[image]

The "3 permissions classified as low impact" are the 3 scopes described above (email, user.read, allow-caller)

However,

If I go to the "Expose an API" blade instead for the **CALLER_APP** and make a scope there, and use that scope in the MSAL call instead, authentication goes through fully, I get a bearer token, and I am able to use the API for what I need.

This method is not mentioned in the documentation, nor any of the readings I've looked into though.

I was wondering if I could get help in understand why I shouldn't use "Expose an API" for my case, as well as why it requires admin consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually the permissions in the API permissions are selected where
   user.read , email are graph permissions and when you mention
   User.Read while calling msal it indirectly means
   https://graph.microsoft.com/User.read which is the basic permission
   to sign in user to read users profile and mail.

- ***But the scope for calling your web api is created by you and it has different AppId or say App ID URI for different applications and its scope needs to be defined uniquely for that App to access that.***
  So actual scopes for that app to access the Api are exposed in expose an api blade which is the scope of the App to access.

> **NOTE**:Actual full value/string of the Scope is the ***concatenation of your web API's Application ID URI and Scope name of scope.*** The
> App ID URI acts as the prefix for the scopes you'll reference in your
> API's code, and it must be globally unique.

*For example,*

- if your web API's application ID URI is https://contoso.com/ and the
  scope name is Employees.Read.All, the full scope is:
  https://contoso.com/Employees.Read.All  or
  `api://<application-client-id>/allow-caller` in your case. [image]
- And coming to the point that it is asking admin consent is , when
  there is no scope that actually means full string scope
  api:///allow-caller , only mentioning
  allow-caller is totally different scope and this new scope may
  require consent from admin as it is not exposed for that particular
  API.

---

Also you can **`add a client application`** in expose an api blade in case you don’t want to see the admin consent as  the "authorized client applications" is used when you basically want to preauthorize users ***without admin consent*** being required to access that api ,***`If not it will prompt users for consent if needed`***.
Please check the below image:

[image]

**References:**

1. [quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-api(github)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis.md#:%7E:text=Select%20Azure%20Active%20Directory%20%3E%20App%20registrations%2C%20and,api%3A%2F%2F%3Capplication-client-id%3E%20or%20another%20supported%20App%20ID%20URI%20pattern.)
2. [azure-expose an Api vs Api-permissions(stackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62438643/azure-expose-an-api-vs-api-permissions)